# React native using axios cant get bearer token

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, axios

I got an api request using axios coming from my backend server. I want to save the bearer token to the device storage or local storage. But when i do `console.log` for the bearer token, it seems not working because what i get is something like a promise.

Here is my method

```
import {AsyncStorage, Alert} from 'react-native';
export default function login(email,password,setLoading){

   console.log('Loading...')
   setLoading(true)

    axios.post('http://52.74.70.6/api/auth/login',{
       email: email,
       password: password
   },{
       headers:{
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
       }
   })
    .then((res)=>{
        setLoading(false)
        AsyncStorage.setItem('bearer_token', res.data.bearer_token);
        console.log(AsyncStorage.getItem('bearer_token'))
        console.log('Loading Finished')
    }).catch((err)=>{
        setLoading(false)
        console.log(err)
        AlertErr()
    })
}
```

What I got is

```
Loading...

Promise {
  "_40": 0,
  "_55": null,
  "_65": 0,
  "_72": null,
}

Loading Finished
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `async/await` with `try/catch` which makes it more readable. Also, you will need to `await` the request to `AsyncStorage` as it returns a promise.

```
import { AsyncStorage, Alert } from "react-native";
export default async function login(email, password, setLoading) {
  console.log("Loading...");
  setLoading(true);
  const url = "http://52.74.70.6/api/auth/login";
  const data = {
    email: email,
    password: password,
  };
  const headers = {
    Accept: "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  };
  try {
    const response = await axios.post(url, data, { headers: headers });
    setLoading(false);
    await AsyncStorage.setItem("bearer_token", res.data.bearer_token);
    console.log(await AsyncStorage.getItem("bearer_token"));
    console.log("Loading Finished");
  } catch (err) {
    setLoading(false);
    console.log(err);
    AlertErr();
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for this. This is the one i currently followed. how do i use the bearer_token in all of my request when i finished login?

Comment: Well, you can add  `Authorization` in your `headers` like this ```{ headers: {"Authorization" : `Bearer ${token}`} }``` , `token = await AsyncStorage.getItem("bearer_token")` . Thanks for the vote @Vince.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's "Async" have you tried to add `await` before it

```
 await AsyncStorage.setItem("bearer_token", res.data.bearer_token);
 console.log(await AsyncStorage.getItem('bearer_token'))
```

or just return the promise in your promise chain

```
then((res)=>{
        setLoading(false)
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('bearer_token', res.data.bearer_token);
        return AsyncStorage.getItem('bearer_token')
    })
.then(token => console.log('token', token)
```

Answer (score 1):

As the name suggests, AsyncStorage is Asynchronous. both setting an item and reading an item from AsyncStorage are asynchronous so you cannot immediately read the results of you insersion.
Accoreding to the [docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/asyncstorage.html), In order to log it you could

```js
AsyncStorage.setItem('bearer_token', res.data.bearer_token).then(() => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('bearer_token').then(console.log)
});
```